# How can I change a bootstrap class for one element which is part of a inner html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I am making a task management web page. When a task is created, I add some inner HTML to the DOM. In the inner HTML, there is a task status label with bootstrap class = 'label label-info' by default. It is looked like this:

[Task manager view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53OUf.png)

I also have a button event function to change this status label from 'Open' to 'Completed'. I want to make this label style from 'label label-info' to  'label label-success' when I click the button.

I tried with JQuery, for some reason it is not working.. I am a total newbie, please let me know where did I do wrong.

Below is the code for adding inner HTML when creating task:

```
var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

  tasksList.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    var id = tasks[i].id;
    var name = tasks[i].name;
    var importance = tasks[i].importance;
    var taskDate = tasks[i].date;
    var note = tasks[i].note;
    var status = tasks[i].status;    

    tasksList.innerHTML += '<div class="well">' +
      '<h6>Task ID: ' + id + '</h6>' +
      '<p><span class="label label-info" id="statusLabel">' + status + '</span></p>' +
      '<h3>' + name + '</h3>' +
      '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> ' + importance + '</p>' +
      '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> ' + taskDate + '</p>' +
      '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> ' + note + '</p>' +
      '<a href="#" onclick="setStatusCompleted(\'' + id + '\')" class="btn btn-success">Complete</a> ' +
      '<a href="#" onclick="deleteTask(\'' + id + '\')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>' +
      '</div>';
```

Below is the code for the button event function to change the text and the style of the label:

```
function setStatusCompleted(id) {
  var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

  for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    if (tasks[i].id == id) {
      tasks[i].status = 'Completed';
      $("#statusLabel").removeClass('label label-info').addClass('label label-success');

    }
  }

  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));

  fetchTasks();
}
```

As you can see I added the JQuery line to remove the style and add the new style, why is it not working?

```
$("#statusLabel").removeClass('label label-info').addClass('label label-success');
```

The expected result, when I click the Complete button, the text of the label will change from 'Open' to 'Complete', also the style of the label will change from 'label label-info' to 'label label-success'.

The actual result is, when I click the Complete button, the text of the label changed from 'Open' to 'Complete', but the style of the label didn't change, it is still 'label label-info'.

Comment: how many elements have this ID `statusLabel`?

Comment: only one time .

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your direct question, but two recommendations to make your code even better. 1.) look into React, you may find it better than jQuery particularly for the "insert inner html" type work or 2.) look at using templates, like nunjucks or handlebars; this can allow you to (almost) completely remove html from your javascript

Comment: Thank you. Love your advice, I never got a chance to work in real web developer position. The advice you gave me let me know my next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you be trying to access a jQuery funtion without actually having JS to access jQuery? Try to nest your jQuery function inside the jQuery access function, and make sure you have the jQuery library linked to you document, like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Or from any other jQuery library supplier. Also you can actually have the library in your documentation as well if you download it from the jQuery official website, just make sure to access it properly, as shown above.

And also, why would you remove the *label* class and then add it again? Maybe there's a reason behind that I can't see, but try this and let me know if it works:

```
function setStatusCompleted(id) {
  var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

  for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    if (tasks[i].id == id) {
      tasks[i].status = 'Completed';
      $(function() {
        $("#statusLabel").removeClass('label-info').addClass('label-success');
      });
    }
  }

  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));

  fetchTasks();
}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you very much. I just need to add  $(function() { ...